# Get value from dynamic json in Android

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

I want to parse this following dynamic JSON

```
{
  "lowfares": {
   "2017-07-30": {
     "price": "1208.00", 
     "tax": "946.00", 
     "totalprice": "2154.00"
   }, 
   "2017-07-31": {
     "price": "1208.00", 
     "tax": "946.00", 
     "totalprice": "2154.00"
    }
  }
}
```

This is my class contains price, tax, and totalprice

```
      public class PriceModel {

        @SerializedName("price")
        private String price;

        @SerializedName("tax")
        private String tax;

        @SerializedName("totalprice")
        private String totalprice;

        public String getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        public void setPrice(String price) {
            this.price = price;
        }

        public String getTax() {
            return tax;
        }

        public void setTax(String tax) {
            this.tax = tax;
        }

        public String getTotalPrice() {
            return totalprice;
        }

        public void setTotalPrice(String totalPrice) {
            this.totalprice = totalPrice;
        }
    }
```

This is my class to contain hashmap to store the response

```
      public class ResponseModel {

            @SerializedName("prices")
            @Expose
            private Map<String,PriceModel> priceModelMap;

            public Map<String, PriceModel> getPriceModelMap() {
                return priceModelMap;
            }

            public void setPriceModelMap(Map<String, PriceModel> priceModelMap) {
                this.priceModelMap = priceModelMap;
            }



        }
```

in API interface, this is how I get the response

```
@GET("getprice/{start}/{end}/1/2")
Call<ResponseModel> getResponse(@Path("start") String start, @Path("end") String end);
```

and in MainActivity, I execute like this

```
     Call call = apiInterface.getResponse("CRB","IMY");
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
            Log.d("TAG",response.code()+" ");
            Log.d("TAG","REsponse: "+response.body());

            ResponseModel responseModel = (ResponseModel) response.body();
            Log.d("TAG","REsponse: "+responseModel.getPriceModelMap());
            Map<String, PriceModel> priceModelMap = responseModel.getPriceModelMap();

            for (Map.Entry<String,PriceModel> entry : priceModelMap.entrySet()){
                String key = entry.getKey();
                PriceModel priceModel = entry.getValue();

                System.out.println("KEY: "+key+" value: "+priceModel.getPrice());

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
            call.cancel();
        }
    });
```

I want to get price, tax, totalprice. But using my method, I tried getPrice method give null value.

How can I get the date and the values from that JSON? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end I decided not to use retrofit as I couldnt find a way to parse the json as I wanted. 
What I did to parse that dynamic json response

```
private HashMap<String,JSONObject> getLowfaresJson(JSONObject data){
    HashMap<String,JSONObject> result = new HashMap<>();


    try {
        JSONObject lowfareJson = data.getJSONObject("lowfares");
        Iterator keys = lowfareJson.keys();

        while ((keys.hasNext())){
            //Getting dynamic key from json
            String currentDynamicKey = (String) keys.next();

            //Getting dynamic value from json
            JSONObject currentDynamicValue = lowfareJson.getJSONObject(currentDynamicKey);
            result.put(currentDynamicKey,currentDynamicValue);

        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;

}
```

that method will return hashmap from dynamic json response. Hope this will help someone

Answer (score 0):

You can simply [gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

Import in your project.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
}

public class TestModel {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String position;
}
```

Use:

```
String strModel ="Staff{name='john', age=35, position='Developer'}"
Gson gson = new Gson();
TestModel testModel = gson.fromJson(strModel, TestModel .class);
```

Read more:[Samples](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/)